# Get current location of user in Alexa Skill (mobile app version)

Tags: geolocation, alexa-skills-kit

I know you can now get the users address in Alexa, but what about the users current location if they use the built in Alexa function in the Amazon Shopping app?

I'd like to make suggestions based on the users current location, not their home address.

Answer (score 2):

Try use Device address API,

https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/device-address-api

Copied from above souce,

Base URIs and Geographic Location of the Skill

The base URI varies depending on the geographic location of your skill, which is a separate value than the device address of the customer’s Alexa device. You can set the apiEndpoint value in the System object to obtain the appropriate base URI.

```
The base URI for US calls for device address data is: https://api.amazonalexa.com/.
The base URI for UK and DE calls for device address data is: https://api.eu.amazonalexa.com
```

The examples on this page use the US URI.
Get Country and Postal Code

Gets the country and postal code associated with a device specified by deviceId. The endpoint is case-sensitive.

```
Endpoint: /v1/devices/*deviceId*/settings/address/countryAndPostalCode
```

Request Message Example

Host: api.amazonalexa.com
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer Atc|MQEWY...6fnLok 
GET https://api.amazonalexa.com/v1/devices/{deviceId}/settings/address/countryAndPostalCode

Request Headers
Header  Description Type    Required
Authorization   A current consent token in the format: Bearer Atc|your consent token|   string  yes
Request Parameters
Parameter   Description     Type    Required
deviceId    The deviceId to retrieve the country and postal code for    string  yes
Response
Successful Response Message Example

This example shows a successful response for a request for “Country & Postal Code”.

Host: api.amazonalexa.com
X-Amzn-RequestId: xxxx-xxx-xxx
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "countryCode" : "US",
  "postalCode" : "98109"
}

Comment: AFAIK this is for the users registered address, for home delivery skills etc. Unless anyone can confirm this will pick up a users location if they use Alexa somewhere else other then home, via the Amazon companion app on their phone.

Comment: So far I know I don't think Alexa can exactly use geolocation other than the registered address

Comment: Thought that might be the case. I guess my skill can work for suggestions near home, or maybe try and let the user speak their current location?